# failed to run grails cmd

Tags: java, grails, centos

I'm using CentOS and grails for hosting a web app. I've set the following in `/.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export GRAILS_HOME=/usr/grails/grails-2.5.6
export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin
```

running `echo $JAVA_HOME`:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

running `echo $GRAILS_HOME`:

```
/usr/grails/grails-2.5.6
```

running `echo $PATH`:

```
......other_paths......
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk/bin:
/usr/grails/grails-2.5.6/bin:
......other_paths......
```

running `java -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_221"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.6.18.1.el7-x86_64 u221-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.221-b02, mixed mode)
```

Finally, when I ran `grails --version`, the console threw me the below:

```
| Error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
| Error         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
| Error         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
| Error         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:236)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:264)
| Error Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.221-2.6.18.1.el7.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/libnet.so: libgconf-2.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
| Error         at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
| Error         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1973)
| Error         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1898)
| Error         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
| Error         at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
| Error         at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
| Error         at sun.net.PortConfig$1.run(PortConfig.java:47)
| Error         at sun.net.PortConfig$1.run(PortConfig.java:45)
| Error         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error         at sun.net.PortConfig.<clinit>(PortConfig.java:44)
| Error         at java.net.SocketPermission$1.run(SocketPermission.java:1218)
| Error         at java.net.SocketPermission$1.run(SocketPermission.java:1210)
| Error         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error         at java.net.SocketPermission.initEphemeralPorts(SocketPermission.java:1209)
| Error         at java.net.SocketPermission.<clinit>(SocketPermission.java:235)
| Error         at sun.security.util.SecurityConstants.<clinit>(SecurityConstants.java:259)
| Error         at java.lang.Class.getProtectionDomain(Class.java:2194)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.define(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:44)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:77)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts$1.run(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:75)
| Error         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.defineClassAndGetConstructor(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:75)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteGenerator.compileStaticMethod(CallSiteGenerator.java:246)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.createStaticMetaMethodSite(CachedMethod.java:290)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.createStaticMetaMethodSite(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:114)
| Error         at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createStaticSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3411)
| Error         at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.createStaticSite(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1308)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:77)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:162)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.<init>(BuildSettings.groovy:836)
| Error         at grails.util.BuildSettings.<init>(BuildSettings.groovy:832)
| Error         at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:156)
| Error         ... 6 more
```

I've spent some time on this but still couldn't manage to solve. Any kind suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your JVM is missing some dependencies.  I'd uninstall/reinstall that.

Some googling led me to posts here and elsewhere suggesting that the JDK and/or JVM that ships with CentOS specifically excludes certain items due to licensing, and so a reinstall can ensure you have a clean and complete copy.

Comment: I use `java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64.rpm` for installing openjdk7 jdk.  I firstly located the designated installing directory by `cd /usr/lib/jvm` where the rpm was put. Then I ran `rpm -ivh java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64.rpm`. The console result was `error: Failed dependencies: java-1.7.0-openjdk = 1:1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8 is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1:1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64 libX11.so.6()(64bit) is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel-1:1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64`. Does this correspond with what you have said

Comment: Sounds like a step in the right direction, though based on the error you pasted here it looks like nothing actually changed.  If I were you I'd search here (or post, if you find nothing) for how to reinstall OpenJDK on CentOS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion to reinstall openjdk. I've used another rpm with version `2.6.18.1` instead of `2.6.22.2`. It turns out working perfectly without any dependency errors.